# It shows error: ' Failed :not master ' when it is executing mongoimport command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It shows error: ' Failed :not master '  when it is executing mongoimport command, as follows:[image]

so ,how could I solve this problem ?

Comment: Does it always fail at 33.9%? What server logs say?

Comment: is it a replica set? if so, are you sure you run mongoimport on the master machine?

Comment: no,just sometimes.

Comment: @OhadR yes,it is replica set,it must run on the master node?

Comment: yes, writes are only done to the Primary.

Comment: Please confirm you connect to the replicaset, not to the master directly. Basically show your mongoimport command.